# LoadError using Atom for Julia

Tags: julia, atom-editor, juno-ide

I am attempting to do a standard install of Julia and the Atom IDE.  I installed Julia 1.4.2 and Atom 1.48.0 as as well as uber-juno on Atom.  Julia appears to have installed fine, but loading the console in Atom results in the following LoadError (have also tried doing this with Julia 1.0.5 with the same result).  Any thoughts greatly appreciated?

```
ERROR: 
LoadError: 
UndefVarError: find_in_path not defined
Stacktrace:

[1] getproperty(::
Module, ::Symbol) at .\sysimg.jl:13
[2] top-level scope at C:\Users\johno\.atom\packages\julia-client\script\boot.jl:3
[3] include at .\boot.jl:317 [inlined]
[4] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at .\loading.jl:1044
[5] include(::Module, ::String) at .\sysimg.jl:29
[6] exec_options(::Base.JLOptions) at .\client.jl:266
[7] _start() at .\client.jl:425
in expression starting at C:\Users\johno\.atom\packages\julia-client\script\boot.jl:1
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue.  The default julia-client and julia-language packages installed in Atom were not up to date.